# How to free memory from the EJB entity instance?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb

In a small project of accounts' management, I've one EJB entity, one EJB stateless, one managed bean (faces-config.xml, with session scope). For presentation tiers, I've some pages that handle with this EJB entity (add an instance to the DataBase, insertion, update, deletion, etc.), everything is alright with DB.

However, when, for exemple, I identify myself, and go to account's creation page, I find the fields (`<h:outputText />`) of the EJB entity are all filled with the account I used for identification.. i tried to use callback methods for EJB entities & EJB stateless, but did not resolved it.

In brief, the objective is to "free" the memory from the instance of this EJB entity (declared as attribute in the managed bean class) in order to find the fields empty whenever I consult them.

How to do that ?

Comment: Are you referencing the managed bean in the `<h:outputText />` ?

Comment: I'm referencing it by that tag for the account's displaying page. And for the account's creation page, i use both of <h:outputText /> and <h:inputText /> to get & set the informations entered.

Comment: Is the account creation page using the same bean as the account display page?

Comment: Yes, i'm using only one JavaBean (defined in faces-config.xml), and its class contains naturally declaration of an interface implemented by the EJB stateless, and of an EJB entity in order to handle with.

Comment: I guess you have to use 1 bean for user identification and 1 for creating a new user. When you're referencing the same bean, it's normal that the page is displaying the same result, since your bean is Session Scoped.

Comment: This means that i should customize a JavaBean per page (that uses it)?
For the callback methods, are they unusful for this situation ?

Comment: No, only when it's necessary. Search for "Managed bean scopes" and learn how to use them properly.

Comment: Returning to your previous answer, i thought u speak about the use (creation) of 2 EJB entites in the JavaBean class, and that what i did and it worked. So if i customize 1 JavaBean for 1,2 or 3 pages, i'll have many of JavaBean in a small project ?
For the callback methods, what do u think ?
In my case, which scope is better to be associated to the only JavaBean class ?

Comment: Thanks my friend Diogo for the answers.